# Magento Products are not displaying under categories section

Tags: magento-1.8

magento products are not displaying  under category section . but displaying in url, in home page.

please check the link " http://joinery.newtrendzonline.com/ "

We created about 500 products. before every products were displaying

If i click "categories", no products displaying.

In browser tab heading "Create new customer account displaying ".

I am struggling for this. please give me solution.

Please post the solution here. you can contact me at realworker99atgmaildotcom

Thanks in Advance......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go to Admin panel -> Catalog -> manage products.
- Click on any product
- Go to "General" tab.
- Make sure the "visibility" attribute is set to "Catalog, Search".

Comment: yes @Mr_Green , It set to catalog, search.

Comment: @user3483987 there might be issue in your project listing template. (by default the name is `list.phtml`, I do not know what you named it though) also check the related layout handle in layout files.

Comment: @user3483987 ok.. check in that and also check in its related layout handle i.e possibly should be `catalog_category_default`. if you can't find any issue in it then post the only important code here.

Comment: This is my list.phtml file http://pastebin.com/cbxsekT3

Comment: @user3483987 `list.phtml` file looks good to me.. somehow the productCollection is being empty. check the layout handle as I mentioned above.

Comment: you can see Catalog.xml here : http://pastebin.com/WzcqDHvr

Comment: If i click on categories, why it displaying In browser tab heading "Create new customer account" .

Comment: @user3483987 sorry, I am not sure what could be the error.

Comment: I really don't have any idea. i did some changes, thank god.... finally products displayed....

Comment: @user3483987 can you explain those changes here? it might help other users who have same issue in future. do it whenever you have time :)

Comment: Before, I created featured products in home page with some method. i deleted all featured products files, may be for that reason, produts were not displaying or may be i did't wrote the correct code for featured products, along with that some settings in backend, we have to select correctly.